# ionic vue background geolocation tracking stops after 5 minute

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor, ionic5

I am using plugin
https://github.com/seididieci/capacitor-backround-geolocation
to watch the user's location. then I am tracking that location with the help of a pusher. this background location works only for 5 minutes after that it just stops. I am using Capacitor's Background task. But that plugin also keeps data on phone after the user opens the app. the Background task sends data to the pusher.

Here is watch location function

```
  getLocation: async function () {
      BackgroundGeolocation.initialize({
        notificationText: "Your app is running, tap to open.",
        notificationTitle: "App Running",
        updateInterval: 10000,
        requestedAccuracy: BgGeolocationAccuracy.HIGH_ACCURACY,
        // Small icon has to be in 'drawable' resources of your app
        // if you does not provide one (or it is not found) a fallback icon will be used.
        smallIcon: "ic_small_icon",
        // Start getting location updates right away. You can set this to false or not set at all (se below).
        startImmediately: true,
      });
      // const geolocation = new Geolocation.Geolocation();
      BackgroundGeolocation.addListener("onLocation", (location) => {
        // console.log("Got new location", location);
        this.subscribe(location.longitude, location.latitude);
        console.log(location)
      });
    
      BackgroundGeolocation.addListener("onPermissions", (location) => {
        // console.log("BGLocation permissions:", location);
        this.subscribe(location.longitude, location.latitude);
        
        // Do something with data
      });
      BackgroundGeolocation.start();
    },
```

Then calling function in mounted()

```
mounted(){
this.getLocation
  App.addListener("appStateChange", (state) => {
       setInterval(this.getLocation, 120000);
      if (!state.isActive) {
        BackgroundTask.beforeExit(async () => {
          setInterval(this.getLocation, 120000);
          console.og('Why')
        });
      }
      if (state.isActive) {
        setInterval(this.getLocation, 120000);
        console.log('Active')
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/foreground-service like this for running the background.